# Fixing a proof that open path connected sets in $\mathbb{C}$ are connected.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

> Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{C}$ be open. Then if $\Omega$ is pathwise connected, then $\Omega$ is connected.

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}$ be open, and suppose we can write $\Omega =\Omega_1\cup \Omega_2$ for disjoint open $\Omega_1,\Omega_2\subset\mathbb{C}$. Let $w_0\in\Omega_1$ and $w_1\in\Omega_2$, and let $\gamma:[0,1]\to\mathbb{C}$ be a path in $\Omega$ with $\gamma(0)=w_1$ and $\gamma(1)=w_2$. Let
\begin{equation}
t^*=\sup_{t\in [0,1]} \{t:\gamma(s)\in\Omega_1,\,0\leq s<t\}.
\end{equation}
If $\gamma(t^*)\in\Omega_1$, there is some $\varepsilon>0$ so that $D_\varepsilon(\gamma(t^*))\subset\Omega_1$, namely, $\gamma(t^*+\varepsilon)\in\Omega_1$, which is a contradiction. But since $\Omega_2$ is open, $\mathbb{C}\setminus\Omega_2$ is closed so it must contain its limit points, $\gamma(t^*)$ is a limit point of $\Omega_1\subset \mathbb{C}\setminus\Omega_2$, and so $\gamma(t^*)\in \Omega_1$, which is a contradiction.

I feel uneasy with the last point of the proof, and was wondering if there was any way I could fix it. Any help/hints/feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Path connected implies connected in general.

Comment: I understand that but I'm trying to fix this proof it's an exercise in my analysis book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your proof looks perfectly good to me; it's essentially the standard proof that a path-connected space (no matter whether it is a subset of $\mathbb C$ or not) is connected.

I would probably insert a new paragraph starting with

> On the other hand, assume $\gamma(t^*)\notin \Omega_1$.

after the first "... which is a contradiction." But that's just style polishing.

It could also make the proof just a smidge clearer if the first "... which is a contradiction" used a few words too say it is specifically a contradiction with the definition of supremum that gave you $t^*$.